# Is it possible for a python file to write another python file?

Tags: python, code-generation

I am creating a worksheet maker for python. Is it possible for me to make python create another .py file and write to it?

```
class ws:

    def _init_(self, number, ctype):
        self.number=wsno
        self.ctype=plang
        x=input('Questions file:')
        y=open(x, mode='r')
        z=f.read()
        a,b,c,d,e=z.split(';')
        wsno=input('Worksheet number: ')
        wspl=input('Language: ')
        title=wspl+" Worksheet "+wsno
        q1="1: "+ws.a
        q2="2: "+ws.b
        q3="3: "+ws.c
        q4="4: "+ws.d
        q5="5: "+ws.e

def renderws():
```

`renderws()` is where I want to make the python file make another python file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you just want to execute it and do not need to save it, simply use `exec()`. Otherwise, just open the file and write to it.

Comment: `open('somefile.py', 'w')`? Python can write to pretty much any kind of file you ask it to, so yes, you can write to a python file

Comment: A Python source file is just a text file; but self-generating code is very frequently an antipattern. Probably the script which wants to execute code in another script could easily execute that code itself anyway.

Comment: suspicious question.

Comment: Typo: `_init_` -> `__init__`

Answer (score 4):

This definitely works:

```
>>> import os
>>> with open( 'test.py', 'w' ) as fout :
...     fout.write( 'print "hello, python"' )
... 
>>> os.system( 'python test.py' )
hello, python
0
>>>
```